# How to select two columns with one as max in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a select query where, I need the Title and Max of Cost in a table;

Any help on this would be really appreciated, thanks!

1) Below query is giving me the all the columns

```
select Title, MAX(sold)
from software
Group by Title, sold;
```

2) Below query is giving me the right result but here I'm hard coding the highest value in 'Sold' column

```
select Title, sold 
from software 
where sold = '84';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select Title, sold from software where sold=(select MAX(sold) from software))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to query something like this which would give the details of max value record in table.

```
select * from software  where sold  = (select  MAX(sold)from software)
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks, your cold worked well.

select title,sold from software  where sold  = (select  MAX(sold)from software);

Answer (score 0):

You were close.  When you are aggregating a field you generally don't want to group by it as well.

This should work for you:

```
    select Title, MAX(sold)
    from software
    Group by Title;
```